# ASP.NET Core Web Application - Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

On Visual Studio 2017, I created an ASP.NET Core Web Application with the following options:
[image]

I haven't changed anything else. 
When I run the project on Debug with Any CPU option (other configurations behave the same), I get the following error:

[image]

I reinstalled .NET core framework, no luck.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, but I still don't know which was the root cause.
My solution:

- reinstall IIS
- reinstall Visual Studio and all .NET Core dependencies
- restart computer.

Now it magically works...

Answer (score 1):

seems likes could not be established connection between iis and  kestrel. do you have customized iis ?

Comment: I didn't customize IIS and it worked perfectly until today. Anyway, I tried hosting in windows service too and I got the same error. I reinstalled IIS and now it magically works...